# What does [..] mean for Rust slices and what is it called?

Tags: string, rust, slice

I've found this example in a README:

```rust
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let filename: &str = &env::args().nth(1).unwrap()[..];
    let filename2: &str = &env::args().nth(1).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", filename);
    println!("{:?}", filename2)
}
```

I'm interested in the first line: `let filename ...`.

What does the `[..]` after the `unwrap` mean?

The second line `let filename2 ...` is my own test that both `filename` and `filename2` are the same, or do I miss something?

What is this `[..]` called?

Comment: It's a [range](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html).

Comment: Pedantically `..` is a [`RangeFull`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeFull.html), `[]` is the indexing / slicing syntax. See also [Appendix B: Operators and Symbols](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/appendix-02-operators.html)

Comment: It is not useless — it converts a `&String` into a `&str` in this case. The `: &str` isn't needed, but it's probably to show the types to make it easier for people to understand the types in play. Your second line does the same thing via `Deref` coercion.

Answer (score 4):

A string can be used as an array of bytes. This addition does strictly nothing:

```
#![feature(core_intrinsics)]

fn print_type_of<T>(_: &T) {
    println!("{}", unsafe { std::intrinsics::type_name::<T>() });
}

fn main() {
    let x = "abc";

    print_type_of(&x); // &str

    let x = &x[..];

    print_type_of(&x); // &str
}
```

`[..]` takes the full range, and `&` takes a reference to it.